# Dockerized Nginx and Gogs not serving assets (404 error)

Tags: nginx, docker

I have set up a Server to serve a website from the standard URL with a containerized Nginx.
This website works completely fine.

On a suburl (/gogs/) I proxy all requests to an instance of GOGS though. This is also containerized and the containers communicate via a custom Docker network.

My problem is, that all the assets from GOGS are not being loaded. I only get 404 errors.

This is from the nginx log:

```
[error] 7#7: *38 open() "/website/gogs/js/libs/clipboard-1.5.9.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: $IP, server: website, request: "GET /gogs/js/libs/clipboard-1.5.9.min.js HTTP/2.0", host: "website"
```

**/website** is a volume that is mounted in the Nginx container.

Here is my config for the proxy:

```
location /gogs/ {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  proxy_pass http://gogs:3000/;
}
```

Most of my Nginx config is based on https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx.

Could this probably be an issue?

How can I resolve the 404 errors that I am seeing?

**EDIT:**
*logs/gogs.log*

```
2017/07/03 04:33:10 [TRACE] Template: user/dashboard/dashboard
```

The other files are empty and there is a broken symlink in the folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   14 Jul  2 21:08 log -> /data/gogs/log
```

I guess this is misconfigured in the docker image provided by gogs.

Comment: Can you share your Gogs configuration as well?

Comment: What does Gogs log show?

Comment: Hi, I have added the only info I could find from the logs and added some nginx config that I thought might be a problem. Does not seem to help much :(

Answer (score 0):

*(Not enough rep to comment...)*

Looks like your containerized nginx doesn't serve static files from Gogs. What Gogs image are you using ? How do you start your containers : `docker run` ? `docker-compose` ?

Might also be helpful to post your Dockerfiles or docker-compose.yml and the nginx conf (at least the `server` section)

Both containers nginx and gogs should share the volume where Gogs stores its code, which I assume is in the website dir on the host. (Let's say it's mounted as `/var/www/html` inside the container).
With Docker :

```
$ docker run -d -v /website:/var/www/html --name gogs gogs
$ docker run -d -v /website:/var/www/html --name nginx --link gogs nginx
```

And your Nginx server config should set `root /var/www/html` so it can find static files :

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    location /gogs/ {
        (proxy_pass...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I am using the gogs from https://github.com/gogits/gogs/tree/master/docker

Linking containers is not advised anymore, as I understand it, that is why I am using a Docker network.

Also Gogs has its own server listening at port 3000. No files are shared between the containers.

Comment: Why do you need nginx in this case ? Please post the commands you used to start your container, and the nginx's container config

Comment: Nginx is just extending the official image with custom nginx.config.

I need Nginx because it is running a website as well.

the server configuration is pretty much what you posted. Just a root and 1 location block that proxies to gogs.

Comment: What's the problem with posting your files and the Docker commands ? I'm not the NSA, I'm just trying to help. Anyways, if your Gogs files are at `/webssite/gogs` (inside the container) (try `docker exec <gogs_container_name> bash -c "ls /website/gogs"`to make sure), your root directive needs to be `/website/gogs` but that might break things with your other website.

Comment: This is a reverse proxy. Nginx does not need to know where the files lie. It seems that you have not really understood my setup. I am not trying to be rude and thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: I had guessed it's a reverse proxy. I've run into a very similar problem with a Wordpress container (reverse-proxied by a nginx container to php-fpm on the WP container with `fastcgi_pass`, though the static files are served directly by Nginx which therefore needs to know where the files are). I wasn't going to try Gogs (Gitea works just fine), but you got me curious, and I would have liked to test your config.